# Umbraco datatype creating Error

Tags: umbraco

I got an error while creating a user control to datatype in Umbraco?.The Error showing is

> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'ASP.usercontrols_xmas_shopshortdesc_ascx' to type
>   'umbraco.editorControls.userControlGrapper.IUsercontrolDataEditor'.]

Anybody know what is this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user control needs to implement 'umbraco.editorControls.userControlGrapper.IUsercontrolDataEditor'.

See [CREATING CUSTOM DATATYPES USING THE UMBRACO USERCONTROL WRAPPER](http://www.nibble.be/?p=24) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

download UComponent add-on & upload it to package. there you may create you own customized 
Data  types with the help of this addon.